# What's the result of integration on a circle on complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

This may be a silly question, but what's the result of $$I=\int_{\partial D(0,R)} 1 \ \mathrm{d}\zeta
$$ My intuition tells me that this should be the perimeter of $D(0, R)$ which is $2\pi R$, but since $1$ is a holomorphic function and $\partial D(0, R)$ is a closed curve, so due to Cauchy's integration theorem, we should have $I=0$.

Can you explain this? Thanks.

Comment: Why should it be the length if the curve? You’re integrating $d\zeta$, not $ds=|d\zeta|$.

Comment: If you wanted the perimeter of $D(0,R)$ the right integral would be $\int_{\partial D(0,R)}\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^1$ where $\mathcal{H}^1$ is $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{C}$. Note that the integral you are dealing with is a *complex line integral* (or *contour integral*), meaning$$\int_{\partial D(0,R)}1\,\mathrm{d}\zeta=\int_0^{2\pi}Rie^{Ri\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta.$$Splitting into real and imaginary parts you should see that you're integrating trigonometric functions over their periods, meaning it cancels (i.e. the result you get from Cauchy's integral theorem).

Comment: If $f$ is analytic everywhere, the integral over a closed curve is zero. In particular, $f(z) =1$ is analytic everywhere.

Comment: Apart from the mentioned general fact (integrals of holomorphic functions along closed contours), in this case it is easy to see that your $d\zeta$'s on opposite points of the circle cancel each other.